# jquery simple online calc, help add some factors

Tags: jquery

here is my - [bad logic](http://jsfiddle.net/funber/kuB38/12/)..)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('form.calc').each(function(){
        $('input[type="hidden"]').not('.ratio').val(0);

        $('select').each(function(){
            var this_name = $(this).attr('name'),
                default_val = $(this).find('option:selected').data('price');
            $('input[name="'+this_name+'"]').val(default_val);
        })

        $('input[name="count"]').val('')
        $('input[name="count_hidden"]').val(500);

        $('span.flag').click(function(){
            var this_flag = $(this),
                flag_id = $(this).attr('id');
            this_flag.toggleClass('active');
            if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                $(this).children('i').removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-check');
                $('input[name="'+flag_id+'"]').val(parseFloat($(this).data('price'))).trigger('change');
            }
            else{
                if($(this).children('i').hasClass('fa-check')){
                    $(this).children('i').removeClass('fa-check').addClass('fa-times');
                }
                $('input[name="'+flag_id+'"]').val('0').trigger('change');
            }
        });

        $('input[name="count"]').keyup(function(){
            var count_val = parseFloat($(this).val())||0,
                this_name = $(this).attr('name');

            if(count_val < 500){
                $(this).addClass('error');
                $('input[name="count_hidden"]').val(0);
            }
            else{
                $(this).removeClass('error');
                $('input[name="'+this_name+'_hidden"]').val(parseFloat(count_val)).trigger('change');
            };

        });

        $('select').change(function(){
            var this_name = $(this).attr('name'),
                this_val = $(this).find("option:selected").data('price');

            $('input[name="'+this_name+'"]').val(parseFloat(this_val)).trigger('change');
        });
        $('input[type="hidden"]').change(function(){
            var flag_val = 0,
                count_val = parseFloat($('input[name="count_hidden"]').val()),
                color_val = parseFloat($('input[name="colors"]').val()),
                material_val = parseFloat($('input[name="materials"]').val());

            $('input.flag').each(function() {
                flag_val += parseFloat($(this).val())||0;
            });

            var values = {};
            $('input.ratio').each(function() {
                var this_val = parseFloat($(this).val());
                this_name = parseFloat($(this).attr('name')),
                    q = count_val-this_name;
                //console.log(this_val, this_name, count_val, q);
                values[this_val] = q;
            });
            $.each(values, function(key, value) {
                //console.log(key);
                var this_value  = value;

            });
            //console.log(values);
            var sum = parseFloat(count_val*(flag_val+color_val+material_val)).toFixed(2);
            $('input[name="sum"]').val(sum);
            $('p.sum').html(sum);
            //console.log(sum);
        });
    });
});
```

a simple online calculator that is left is the last to add the reduction factor, depending on the quantity of input name=count
in real wep_app all values get from BD, due to this decision based on the statics are not accepted)

sorry for my bad bad eng )

my solution:

```
 var values = {},
                range_array =[];

            $('input.ratio').each(function() {
                var this_val = parseFloat($(this).val());
                    this_name = parseFloat($(this).attr('name')),
                    q = count_val-this_name;
                if(q > 0){
                    values[this_val] = q;
                    range_array.push(q);
                    //console.log(varrr);
                } 
            });
            //console.log(values, range_array);
            var min = Math.min.apply(null, range_array);
            console.log(min);

            var z = 1;
            $.each(values, function(key, value){
                if(value == min){
                    z = key;
                }              
            });
            //console.log(z);
            //console.log(val_arr);




            var sum = parseFloat(z*count_val*(flag_val+color_val+material_val));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. What are you trying to do?

Comment: in html block hidden input.ratio this reduction factor (name = range value, val = value of the coefficient)

Comment: I'm trying to add to this application the opportunity to reduce the total value depending on the number entered in the field named "count"

Comment: trying to make it through the array, generating input type hidden class "ratio", where name = Range value = coefficient value, calculate the difference between the input quantity and range, create an array - the difference values ​​= Coefficient value, on the logic I need to pull out array of key-value pair with the smallest positive value, the question is how to do it?

Comment: in code  ---var values = {};
            $('input.ratio').each(function() {
                var this_val = parseFloat($(this).val());
                this_name = parseFloat($(this).attr('name')),
                    q = count_val-this_name;
                //console.log(this_val, this_name, count_val, q);
                values[this_val] = q;
            });

Comment: sorry, i use google translater

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = {},
            range_array =[];

        $('input.ratio').each(function() {
            var this_val = parseFloat($(this).val());
                this_name = parseFloat($(this).attr('name')),
                q = count_val-this_name;
            if(q > 0){
                values[this_val] = q;
                range_array.push(q);
                //console.log(varrr);
            } 
        });
        //console.log(values, range_array);
        var min = Math.min.apply(null, range_array);
        console.log(min);

        var z = 1;
        $.each(values, function(key, value){
            if(value == min){
                z = key;
            }              
        });
        //console.log(z);
        //console.log(val_arr);




        var sum = parseFloat(z*count_val*(flag_val+color_val+material_val));
```